# Getting table values from checkbox in rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/ae2kqtnn/1/). How can I push values of checked rows in JS Array or Object?

```
var obj=[
    {
        id : "001",
        name : "apple",
        category : "fruit",
        color : "red"
    },
    {
        id : "002",
        name : "melon",
        category : "fruit",
        color : "green"
    },
    {
        id : "003",
        name : "banana",
        category : "fruit",
        color : "yellow"
    }
]
$.each(obj, function (index, item) {
     var eachrow = "<tr>"
                 + "<td id="+index+"><input type='checkbox'></td>"
                 + "<td>" + item["id"] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item["name"] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item["category"] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item["color"] + "</td>"
                 + "</tr>";
     $('#tbody').append(eachrow);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one,

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ae2kqtnn/5/)

You will get desired output once you click get rows button.

```
$("#btn").on("click",function(){

    var checkedRows = [];
    $("#tbody tr").each(function(){

        if($(this).find("input").is(":checked")){
            checkedRows.push($(this).find("td:eq(1)").html());
        }    
        console.log(checkedRows);    
    });

    var result = [];

    $.each(obj,function(item){
        if(checkedRows.indexOf(item.id)>-1)
       result.push(item) ;
    });   

      console.log(result);    

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you could try something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
    data.push($(this).parent().attr('id'));
  });
});
```

Updated [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ae2kqtnn/3/)